# Why does a variable disappear when swapping the list of the odd number of variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Why does six disappear when swapping the list of the odd number of variables in the below code?

```
In [1]: A = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6]

In [2]: A[:2], A[2:] = A[2:],  A[:2]

In [3]: A
Out[3]: [9, 7, 3, 8]

In [4]: B = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6]

In [5]: B[2:] + B[:2]
Out[5]: [9, 7, 6, 3, 8]

In [6]: C = [3, 8, 9, 7]

In [7]: C[:2], C[2:] = C[2:],  C[:2]

In [8]: C
Out[8]: [9, 7, 3, 8]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
A[:2], A[2:] = A[2:],  A[:2]
```

effectively resolves to:

```
# A = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6]
tmp1 = A[2:]  # tmp1 = [9, 7, 6]
tmp2 = A[:2]  # tmp2 = [3, 8]
A[:2] = tmp1  # A = [9, 7, 6, 9, 7, 6]
A[2:] = tmp2  # A = [9, 7, 3, 8]
```

List slicing is weird, and a larger slice can replace *all the elements* in a smaller slice, thus expanding the list. Similarly, a smaller slice can replace a larger slice, thus removing elements that used to be there.

That's what's happening here - the evaluation order, in which `A[:2]` gets fully evaluated before `A[2:]`, means that the assignment to `A[2:]` ends up overwriting one of the values inserted by `A[:2]`.

For a situation like this, you're better off using concatenation than multiple assignment, like you do with list `B` in your example.

Comment: If the original list needs to be destructively modified, you can use `A[:] = A[2:] + A[:2]`.  This fully constructs the new list before updating `A` (it's equivalent to creating a new list, then replacing the contents of `A` with the contents of the new list).